# selector does not find in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I click on the div element on the web page, then I get the content of the web page, but the element that I am sure exists gives different results every time I start the server, for example, although I do not make any coding changes, sometimes it finds the element and brings the results I want, but sometimes it cannot find it and gives an error, 'wait until -> load/domcontentloaded' and waitUntilSelector etc. I have done many experiments, I have checked the selector field many times, I have tried other selectors that trigger the click event, but unfortunately, every time sometimes it gives an error and sometimes not.

Error : No element found for selector:

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent(
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2.1 Safari/605.1.15"
    );
    await page.goto(
      "https://www.tripadvisor.com.tr/Airline_Review-d8729174-Reviews-or550-Turkish-Airlines#REVIEWS",
      { waitUntil: 'load' }
    );

    //.TnInx
    //.ui_icon.caret-down.Lvqmo
    //caret-down Lvqmo
    //.Ignyf._S.Z
    //lszDU
    //#component_1 > div > div.QbfDN > div > div > div.ui_column.is-8-desktop.is-12-tablet.is-12-mobile > div.ui_container.DrjGF > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.WAllg._T > div.vTVDc > div._T.FKffI.bmUTE > div.lszDU
    await page.click(".Ignyf._S.Z");
```

I would appreciate your help, thank you very much in advance

Comment: @ggorlen https://www.tripadvisor.com.tr/Airline_Review-d8729174-Reviews-or550-Turkish-Airlines#REVIEWS , thanks

Comment: OK, thanks. So what are you trying to do on the page? I'm a bit unclear of the goal.

Comment: @ggorlen , Actualy when i click the div who the class name ‘.Ignyf’ opening some fields i need (ratings , rating text etc.) , i wrote that code, but there a problem when the bot click a div, i wrote the situation at above , thanks

Comment: Can you show the expected output?